# Error casting object from rest ( conversion not allowed )

Tags: rest, restsharp

I will try to explain the problem:

1- From server side I got a class called Document what extends from class Node ( several classes extends from Node ).

2- From rest API, I got a service what sends as response Node objects ( Document or other what extends from Node ). Rest output really is sending all information ( document etc... ).

3- When arrive at rest client I get as Node class ( no problem until here all goes fine ).

```
if (node.GetType() == typeof(Document))
{
  // never goes into
  var doc = (Document)node;
}

if (node is Document)
{
  // never goes into
  var doc = (Document)node;
}
```

4- The problem comes when I looking for if Node is type of Document the answer is always false.

Before somebody answering me is not possible ( I'm doing exactly the same with java and php without problems ). I do not find the key ( in java for example there's some annotation what helps on it @XmlSeeAlso({Document.class, Folder.class, Record.class, Mail.class }) ).

I do not know if it's possible doing it with restcharp or I must go on more low level implemetnation. Any clue or help on it is appreciated.

Here some code:

```
// Query result List
public class QueryResultList
{
  public  List<QueryResult> queryResults { get; set; } 
}

// Query Result
public class QueryResult
{
  public Node node { get; set; }
}

// Class Node
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Globalization;

using System.Xml.Serialization;


namespace com.openkm.sdk4csharp.bean
{
    public class Node
    {
        private static long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        public static String AUTHOR = "okm:author";
        public static String NAME = "okm:name";

        public DateTime created { get; set; }
        public String path { get; set; }
        public String author { get; set; }
        public int permissions { get; set; }
        public String uuid { get; set; }
        public bool subscribed { get; set; }
        public long nodeClass { get; set; }
        public List<String> subscriptors { get; set; }
        public List<String> keywords { get; set; }
        public List<Folder> categories { get; set; }
        public List<Note> notes { get; set; }
        //public String linkTarget { get; set; }
        //public Version actualVersion { get; set; }
        //public Boolean promotedAsRecord { get; set; }

        public String toString() 
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("{");
            sb.Append("path=").Append(path);
            sb.Append(", permissions=").Append(permissions);
            sb.Append(", created=").Append(created == null ? null : created.GetDateTimeFormats());
            sb.Append(", subscribed=").Append(subscribed);
            sb.Append(", nodeClass=").Append(nodeClass);
            sb.Append(", subscriptors=").Append(subscriptors);
            sb.Append(", uuid=").Append(uuid);
            sb.Append(", keywords=").Append(keywords);
            sb.Append(", categories=").Append(categories);
            sb.Append(", notes=").Append(notes);
            // sb.Append(", linkTarget=").Append(linkTarget);
            //sb.Append(", actualVersion=").Append(actualVersion);
            //sb.Append(", promotedAsRecord=").Append(promotedAsRecord);
            sb.Append("}");
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
}


// Class Document
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Globalization;

namespace com.openkm.sdk4csharp.bean
{
    public class Document:Node
    {
        private static long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public static String TYPE = "okm:document";
        public static String CONTENT = "okm:content";
        public static String CONTENT_TYPE = "okm:resource";
        public static String SIZE = "okm:size";
        public static String LANGUAGE = "okm:language";
        public static String VERSION_COMMENT = "okm:versionComment";
        public static String NAME = "okm:name";
        public static String TEXT = "okm:text";
        public static String TITLE = "okm:title";
        public static String DESCRIPTION = "okm:description";

        public String title { get; set; }
        public String description { get; set; }
        public String language { get; set; }
        public DateTime lastModified { get; set; }
        public String mimeType { get; set; }
        public Boolean locked { get; set; }
        public Boolean checkedOut { get; set; }
        public Version actualVersion { get; set; }
        public LockInfo lockInfo { get; set; }
        public Boolean signed { get; set; }
        public Boolean convertibleToPdf { get; set; }
        public Boolean convertibleToSwf { get; set; }
        public Boolean convertibleToDxf { get; set; }
        public String cipherName { get; set; }
        //public String annotations { get; set; }

      public String toString() 
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.Append("{");
                sb.Append("path=").Append(path);
                sb.Append(", title=").Append(title);
                sb.Append(", description=").Append(description);
                sb.Append(", mimeType=").Append(mimeType);
                sb.Append(", author=").Append(author);
                sb.Append(", permissions=").Append(permissions);
                sb.Append(", created=").Append(created == null ? null : created.GetDateTimeFormats());
                sb.Append(", lastModified=").Append(lastModified == null ? null : lastModified.GetDateTimeFormats());
                sb.Append(", keywords=").Append(keywords);
                sb.Append(", categories=").Append(categories);
                sb.Append(", locked=").Append(locked);
                sb.Append(", lockInfo=").Append(lockInfo);
                sb.Append(", subscribed=").Append(subscribed);
                sb.Append(", subscriptors=").Append(subscriptors);
                sb.Append(", uuid=").Append(uuid);
                sb.Append(", convertibleToPdf=").Append(convertibleToPdf);
                sb.Append(", convertibleToSwf=").Append(convertibleToSwf);
                sb.Append(", convertibleToDxf=").Append(convertibleToDxf);
                sb.Append(", cipherName=").Append(cipherName);
                sb.Append(", notes=").Append(notes);
                //sb.Append(", annotations=").Append(annotations);
                sb.Append("}");
                return sb.ToString();
            }
    }
}



QueryResultList ret = new QueryResultList();
IRestRequest request = new RestRequest(uriHelper.SEARCH_FIND_BY_CONTENT, Method.GET);
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Xml;
request.AddParameter("content", content, ParameterType.QueryString);
IRestClient client = getClient(url, user, password);
IRestResponse<QueryResultList> response = client.Execute<QueryResultList>(request);

// here when I iterate results -> node and try to cast to Document fails
...
```

Comment: Please show a sample of your data. It's not clear how the parser is meant to "know" that it should parse a particular node as a `Document` node.

Comment: I've updated with complete class Node and Document. From rest service I do Node node = (Node) Document; and sent all objects as Node. When I'm in client side I would like to identify what are type of Document etc.. and do the reverse action Document doc = (Document) node;

Comment: In java for example we use the annotation @XmlSeeAlso({Document.class, Folder.class, Record.class, Mail.class })
public class Node implements Serializable { what helps the serialization. On php with httpful I've got own deserializer what evaluates the data and then parse document etc.. Which is my scneario ' create my own serializer or there's some way for doing magic :)

Comment: There's still no indication of the JSON, and it would be useful to provide a *short* but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Here there's some code for testing [http://tinyurl.com/npbjo6q] and here the request and response [http://tinyurl.com/nrn49np]. Hope this could be useful.

Comment: No, you've missed the point. The question itself should have a *short* (not 127K!) but complete program demonstrating the problem, with *small* request/response messages where necessary.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know how doing it more simple and I do not know how explain more easilly. It's a rest service created by java and I'm doing rest client based on .net, finally I've created my own deserializer. The problem is that same rest method can response a list several types of objects into ( Document or Folder what extends from same class Node ). In java client is possible deserialize automatically the list and convert each object to Document, Folder etc... but seems on .net is not possible and must build your own deserializer.